# How to extract email from html link

Tags: c#

Hi I have a csv file which I need to format  (columns) email, they are in the csv as follows

```
<a href=\mailto:john@domain.com\">john@domain.com</a>"
<a href=\mailto:dave.h@domain22.co.uk\">dave.h@domain22.co.uk</a>"
```

etc...

So i want to remove `<a href=\mailto:john@domain.com\"> </a>"` and just use john@domain.com

I have the following

```
foreach (var clientI in clientImportList)
                            {
newClient = new DomainObjects.Client();
//Remove unwanted email text??
                                newClient.Email = clientI.Email
                            }
```

Comment: Do you have to use the second address? Using the first would be way easier and in your example they are identical.

Comment: Have you done any research on substrings and regular expressions?

Comment: Get the index of the ">" symbol, then get the index of the "<" symbol that comes after that, perform a SubString.

Comment: second address would be the next row

Comment: Yes I guess using the  remove everything before and including > and then everything after and including < I have not used the index approach before, simple?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I usually write myself little utility classes and extensions to handle things like this. Since this probably won't be the last time you have to do something like this you could do this:

Create an Extension of the string class:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ExtractMiddle(this string text, string front, string back)
    {
        text = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(front) + 1);
        return text.Remove(text.IndexOf(back));
    }
}
```

And then do this(Could use better naming, but you get the point):

```
string emailAddress = text.ExtractMiddle(">", "<");
```

Comment: `IndexOf` takes a `char` not a `string`. So if you use  this to pass a `string` more than 1 character, the results are unpredictable.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use HtmlAgilityPack and not parse it yourself:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
{
    string href = link["href"].Value;
    // use "mailto:john@domain.com" here..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test regular expressions here:
https://regex101.com/

Using your example, this seems to work:

```
mailto:(.*?)\\">
```

The library needed for regex is:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it the index way, something like:

```
        const string start = "<a href=\\mailto:";
        const string end = "\\\">";
        string asd1 = "<a href=\\mailto:john@domain.com\\\">john@domain.com</a>\"";
        int index1 = asd1.IndexOf(start);
        int startPosition = index1 + start.Length;
        int endPosition = asd1.IndexOf(end);
        string email = asd1.Substring(startPosition, endPosition - startPosition);
```